# Inserting a string element in the beginning of an array in Java with loops without making the last element disappear

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Create an algorithm using JAVA language that will insert an array element to the BEGINNING of the array given.

the first array elements are as follows:

John, Cecille, Mark, Judas, Theresa

Example:

Insert Element to insert: Martha

New Updated List: Martha, John, Cecille, Mark, Judas, Theresa

This is my attempt, unfortunately "Theresa" at the end keeps disappearing:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ArraySample1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String[] names = new String[] {"John", "Cecille", "Mark", "Judas", "Theresa"};
       int x = 1, n = 5;
       int i = 0, y = n;

        System.out.println("The original array elements are: ");

       for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
       System.out.println("NAME[" + i + "] = " + names[i] + " ");
       }
    
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter element to insert: ");
      String item = sc.next();
    
      for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
        for(y = n-1; y > i; y--){ 
        names[y]=names[y-1];
        }
      names[i] = item;
      }             
    
     System.out.println("The array elements after insertion :");

     for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     System.out.println("NAME[" + i + "] = " + names[i] + " ");
     }
   }
}
```

[Output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Riy.png)

As you can see from the pic, Theresa disappears. I have tried to insert an n=n+1 anywhere in the code in hopes of increasing the number of elements, but when I run the program, it returns an "out of bounds"

Comment: of course that name disappears. Arrays have a fixed size in Java. You can't just add another element (at the start or at the end) and expect it to work like that. You'll need to create a new array with length+1 elements, fill the first spot with the new element, and all the next ones with the elements you already had

Comment: Alright thanks! I'll try it out

Comment: I think for what you are doing, an array is the wrong thing. You should havee a look at ArrayList. There you can just insert an element ant the arrayList automatically adjusts its size for you. Allocating a complete new (bigger) array and copying the whole array into that is just a hell lot of overhead for inserting one element.

Comment: @Juerrrgen cosidering the way it is phrased, it is likely to be an assignment. If so, and she uses an ArrayList, she will fail, since she's not following the assignment

Comment: Of course, if it is an assignment, returning a new array is fine. But i would not recommend doing that in production code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can not use same array, since array size is fixed in Java. For solving this task, you can simply use ArrayList, which doesn't have fixed size. (ArrayList uses array at the back). If not, you can use array as follows:

```
String[] names = new String[] {"John", "Cecille", "Mark", "Judas", "Theresa"};
names = Arrays.copyOf(names, names.length+1);
```

and use your same logic...

This way your array will have one more cell added at the end of it.